# how to write a macro in ms access that will run sql

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I write a macro in MS Access that will automatically run multiple SQL queries and also save them simultaneously? If I choose the OpenQuery action then it needs a query that is already saved but I want to run queries on multiple tables using macros, is there any way to do this!

Comment: Can't use macros. VBA and QueryDef might get you what you want but not entirely clear what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple function to create the query. Then you only need to run it. If you don't supply a name, the query will not be stored (temporary).

Create query:

```
Private Function CreateQueryDefinition(ByVal qryName As String, ByVal sqlCommand As String) As DAO.QueryDef
    Set CreateQueryDefinition = CurrentDb().CreateQueryDef(qryName, sqlCommand)
End Function
```

To call it:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim q As DAO.QueryDef
    Set q = CreateQueryDefinition("QueryName", "UPDATE Table SET Table.Field = 'Whatever';")
        q.Execute dbFailOnError

End Sub
```

Note an error will be thrown if you try to create a query that already exists.